# Getting Row with max Sum value in Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a query, but I can't the max from each row.

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.ProductName, Sum(OD.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, S.SupplierID
FROM Products AS P, Suppliers AS S, OrderDetails AS OD, Orders O                  
WHERE S.SupplierID=P.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=OD.ProductID 
And O.OrderDate >=#01/01/2017# And O.OrderDate<#01/01/2018# 
And O.OrderID=OD.OrderID  
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.ProductName, S.SupplierID   
ORDER BY Sum(OD.Quantity) DESC
```

I Tried doing Limit 1 and Having Max,but it doesn't work. I also can't do Max(SUM) Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which column you want the max of? If you want the top n-rows you can use SELECT TOP n ....FROM...WHERE...etc. Where n is a number like 1 or 10.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 P.ProductID, P.ProductName, Sum(OD.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, S.SupplierID
FROM ((Products AS P INNER JOIN
       Suppliers AS S
       ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
      ) INNER JOIN
      OrderDetails AS OD
      ON P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Orders O 
     ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID                 
WHERE O.OrderDate >= #01/01/2017# And
      O.OrderDate < #01/01/2018# 
 GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.ProductName, S.SupplierID   
ORDER BY Sum(OD.Quantity) DESC
```